# Deleted item showing up in search results

Tags: c#, sharepoint, search

I have created and deleted a site page in sharepoint 2010 site.But it is still showing in the search results..For your information I've deleted from the recycle bin also...Please let me know if any configuration have to do for the search...

Comment: Have you full crawled the content source since deleting the page?  Does the page show up in the crawl log?  What is the status of the page in the crawl log success/warning/error?

Answer (score 0):

The items are indexed, you don't search the actual items but only a reference to them.

See this article

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/starting-a-full-update-of-a-content-index-HA001160506.aspx

Comment: Still facing the same issue :(